# Pyspark code doesn't work in a UDF on Databricks

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to understand what's happening behind the scenes when I try to deploy a UDF in Databricks. I want this UDF to be used by others and I plan to expanding it with more logic later on.

Consider the following code:

```
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  def my_udf(serialnum_input):
    df = spark.sql("Select serialnum, datetime, totalcounts from mysqltableinDBX")
    totalcounts = df.filter(df.serialnum == serialnum_input).agg(F.sum(df.totalcounts)).collect()[0][0]
    return totalcounts
```

This deploys fine and if I attempt to run it by passing a known **serialnum** that is present in the underlying table, I get result as expected:

```
%sql
select my_udf(12345) as UDF_Result

# This returns the correct sum of all the totalcounts for serial 12345
```

However when I try to wrap this as a function, I get a NULL result:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_udf(serialnum_input INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
AS
$$
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  def my_udf(serialnum_input):
    df = spark.sql("Select serialnum, datetime, totalcounts from mysqltableinDBX")
    totalcounts = df.filter(df.serialnum == serialnum_input).agg(F.sum(df.totalcounts)).collect()[0][0]
    return totalcounts
$$
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the second function, wrapping your code in a `def` block prevents its execution. Remove the `def`:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_udf(serialnum_input INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
AS
$$
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  df = spark.sql("Select serialnum, datetime, totalcounts from mysqltableinDBX")
  totalcounts = df.filter(df.serialnum == serialnum_input).agg(F.sum(df.totalcounts)).collect()[0][0]
  return totalcounts
$$
```

If you *really* want to leave the `def` there, add a top-level `return` to your function:

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_udf(serialnum_input INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
AS
$$
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F

  def my_udf(serialnum_input):
    df = spark.sql("Select serialnum, datetime, totalcounts from mysqltableinDBX")
    totalcounts = df.filter(df.serialnum == serialnum_input).agg(F.sum(df.totalcounts)).collect()[0][0]
    return totalcounts

  return my_udf(serialnum_input)
$$
```

The [relevant documentation page's examples](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html#create-python-functions) reflect this.

Comment: i tried both but I get the same error SparkRuntimeException: [UDF_USER_CODE_ERROR.GENERIC] Execution of function failed. When i expand it, it says 
== Error ==
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined

Comment: I assume its a missing library?